# Notifications via messages on order updates/changes

Tags: notification, order

I am currently working on fixing the design problems of a marketplace. This marketplace place sends multiple notifications via email, account notifications, and messages whenever there is an update on the order which I think is a little bit too much, especially on the messaging part. Here's the screenshot of the issue: [image]

My question is, what is the best practice when it comes to notifications about orders? Is it okay to remove the message notifications? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all notification types (email, account and messages) sending the same information? If so, it would probably be enough to stick to email and account notifications, and send emails for the more important steps in the order process to avoid overwhelming the user. You could also consider doing some A/B testing to see which notification types users interact with the most. This article might be useful: https://uxplanet.org/how-to-design-notifications-for-better-ux-6fb0711be54d

Comment: Thank you so much!